# Having problems accessing $_GET values

Tags: variables

I'm trying to get the value of a $_GET variable on the homepage of my site. For some reason I can't access any $_GET variables on the homepage, but I can access them just fine on other pages. Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: can you give us some sample code?  $_GET should be accessible in all pages. what do you get when u do echo $_GET  ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the reason is that WordPress uses the default query on the homepage, which maybe the reason why you are getting an empty array for `$_GET`.